# How to catch g-recaptcha-response in ASP.NET ApiController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, recaptcha

I am trying to post the form with ReCaptcha to ApiController.

```
<form>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" ><br/>    
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" ><br/>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="some_site_key"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('form').submit(function (event) {
            var data = $('form').serialize();
            console.log('form data: ', data);
            $.post("api/test", data,
                function (data) {
                alert('success');
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Form the `console.log()` statement, I can see the values posted are under names of **name**, **email** and **g-recaptcha-response**.

I thought I could have a view model at the ApiController, like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(FormModel model)
{
   // automatic model binding to get the posted data.
}

public class FormModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string GRecaptchaResponse { get; set; }
}
```

But obviously there is no rule to bind `g-recaptcha-response` to `GRecaptchaResponse`. And a valid property name should not contain a dash `-`.

So the question is, how can we receive the `g-recaptcha-response` value at the server (ApiController) end?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've found:

In ApiController:

```
public async Task Post()
{
    var obj = await Request.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>();
    var model = obj.ToObject<FormModel>();        
    //...
}
```

For the `FormModel`, use `[JsonProperty]`:

```
public class FormModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("g-recaptcha-response")]
    public string GRecaptchaResponse { get; set; }
}
```